How to add OAuth2 protocol in ADFS
I tried to get token from ADFS server in postman.
POST https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/token


This is the response:

Error Detail: MSIS7065 :there are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token

And also, in authorize request case is same return error:
I am checking configuration by request that
https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/well-known/openid-configuration.

In Json data:

issuer value (https://{adfs-domai}/adfs) url page show 503 error
authorization_endpoint, token_endpoint show same error MSIS7065
jwks_uri may be is working, return key [ { kty, use, alg and so on } ]

Json response:
{
    "issuer": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/authorize/",
    "token_endpoint": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/token/",
    "jwks_uri": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/discovery/keys",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_basic",
        "private_key_jwt",
        "windows_client_authentication"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "id_token",
        "code id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "query",
        "fragment",
        "form_post"
    ],
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "refresh_token",
        "client_credentials",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "implicit",
        "password",
        "srv_challenge",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
        "device_code"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "pairwise"
    ],
    "scopes_supported": [
        "vpn_cert",
        "openid",
        "user_impersonation",
        "logon_cert",
        "allatclaims",
        "profile",
        "winhello_cert",
        "aza",
        "email"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "access_token_issuer": "http://{adfs-domain}/adfs/services/trust",
    "claims_supported": [
        "aud",
        "iss",
        "iat",
        "exp",
        "auth_time",
        "nonce",
        "at_hash",
        "c_hash",
        "sub",
        "upn",
        "unique_name",
        "pwd_url",
        "pwd_exp",
        "mfa_auth_time",
        "sid",
        "nbf"
    ],
    "microsoft_multi_refresh_token": true,
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/userinfo",
    "capabilities": [
        "kdf_ver2"
    ],
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/logout",
    "as_access_token_token_binding_supported": true,
    "as_refresh_token_token_binding_supported": true,
    "resource_access_token_token_binding_supported": true,
    "op_id_token_token_binding_supported": true,
    "rp_id_token_token_binding_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/devicecode"
}

The returned values are the same as in the JSON above, and it appears that items like "password" are supported under the grant_types_supported field. However, I am curious about the reason for the MSIS7065 error. Can anyone provide more information?

The URL in the discovery document ends with a slash. You're recommended to read that document and use the exact urls they give you.

One thing I found out is that when making a request that POST https://{adfs-domain}/adfs/oauth2/token, the same error as mentioned above (MSIS7065) occurs if the client_id is incorrect.
